# xpath won't retrieve elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Here is the URL of the xml source:

I'm tryng to grab all the RichText elements using xpath relative location and then print the elementID attribute.  It is outputting nothing though.  Any ideas?

```
<?php  

$url = "FXG";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);     
//print_r($xml);    
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//RichText");    
$count = count($textNode);    
$i = 0;    
while($i < $count)
{    
   echo '<h1>'.$textNode[$i]['s7:elementID'].'</h1>';
   $i++;
}    

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the namespaces that are set in the xml

```
$url = "http://testvipd7.scene7.com/is/agm/papermusepress/HOL_12_F_green?&fmt=fxgraw";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);       
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s7', 'http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText/@s7:elementID");
foreach($textNode as $node) {
    echo '<h1>'.$node[elementID].'</h1>';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your input.  it is working and this will definitely help me going forward!

Comment: i added a new question building on what you had suggested.  I am getting unexpected array results though:

Answer (score 0):

Strange. This, however, works.

```
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//*[name() = 'RichText']");
```